# Set environment variable in Jenkins from file on a remote host

Tags: linux, bash, jenkins, ssh, continuous-integration

I need to inject an environment variable to a Jenkins job from a properties file located on a different machine. The Inject plugin can only set variables from the local machine as far as I can see.

Is there a was to set environment variable that are store on a remote machine?

Comment: Can you use scp in a bash build step to move the remote file to the local machine and then inject the variable?  You could overwrite the old version of the file every time you copy the new one, or delete the file after you have the variable injected.

Comment: I don't have access to the jenkins slave so that is not an option. Is there anyway to parse output of the console on jenkins?

Comment: I'm assuming you are talking about the console output for a jenkins job and not the jenkins CLI console. I don't know if that's possible to do within the same job in real time.  If you want to parse the console output of another (or previously) completed job you can find the console output of each build saved to a log file you can find like so `Jenkins Home Folder\jobs\<job name>\builds\<build number>\log` That path comes from a windows server, but I believe it should be the same.  You should be able to open that file and parse it as you need.